# How to add a toggle on the left side of my page?

Tags: menus, widgets

How to add a toggle on the left side of my page and the content on the right side of my wordpress page.
The toggle should behave like a menu on the left side(the arrangement)and each heading would have a icon and when i click over that it should display the list of other pages like submenu.
Is that Possible?[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: ...]

Please try something yourself. Stack Overflow is not like other websites in terms of "other people do my work".